# Set operations on pcl indices

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if PCL specific questions are welcome here but:

I'm looking at doing standard set operations on indices of PCL point clouds. I can certainly implement such a thing myself, but would prefer to do it some standard/canonical way. Unfortunately after a bit of searching I'm seeing no evidence that such functionality exists natively.

Can someone verify one way or another: Is there a cannoical way to do set operations on PCL point cloud indices?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173957/set-operations-on-pcl-indices/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would [pcl::PointIndices class](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_indices.html) be what you are looking for? Throughout a lot of PCL code, they use these indices to select which point in a cloud to perform a particular operation on. Most of the core filters have a "SetInputCloud" and "SetIndices" functions and then a "filter" or "segment" or "extract" or whatnot function that acts on that subset of the cloud (if no indices are set, it is assumed to use the entire cloud).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2014-06-24**:
I ended up creating a collection of functions for std::sort and std::set_union/difference etc reaching into  the guts of `PointIndices` But, I'm surprised the functionality doesn't exist as reaching into the guts of a custom data type and performing such operations is a development no-no/code-smell.